# How to stretch OpenGL fullscreen app with Win32 API's DEVMODE?

Tags: c++, opengl

I am trying to stretch an 800x600 screen to the dimensions of a full screen. I am currently getting black borders around the 800x600 portion. I'm using the Win32 API with OpenGL.

This is being called when entering full screen:

```
    DEVMODE dmScreenSettings;

    memset(&dmScreenSettings, 0, sizeof(dmScreenSettings));
    dmScreenSettings.dmSize = sizeof(dmScreenSettings);
    dmScreenSettings.dmPelsWidth = win->width;
    dmScreenSettings.dmPelsHeight = win->height;
    dmScreenSettings.dmBitsPerPel = SCREEN_BPP; 
    dmScreenSettings.dmFields = DM_BITSPERPEL | DM_PELSWIDTH | DM_PELSHEIGHT;
```

Is there a way to stretch with DEVMODE?

Note: there is a .dmScale member, but I had no luck with it.

Comment: in your gl functions, do you have a viewport function call? if yes, adapt it to your screen settings.

Comment: The code you listed sets the display resolution, not the dimensions of your window's client area. The two are independent.

Comment: I do have a viewport function. It has {0,0,800,600}, but when I expand it to {0,0,1280,600} it has no effect.   Now before my code above, If I change {0,0,800,600} to my desktop resolution's width to 1280 it adjusts just fine, but the 600 makes it look like a widescreen film. The issue is I want it {0,0,800,600} stretched out, rather than adding 480 pixels to the width. I don't know if that's making it clearer or worse. I guess it just takes some trial and error. Thanks for the thoughts so far.

Comment: Side advice: if you are learning the great and portable OpenGL, why not use a window manager that is also great and portable? Binding yourself to windows only means a headache when you realize the world is not just Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Please don't change the display device mode. Doing that alters the physical signal going to the screen and may mess up the user Desktop's icon arrangement. User's don't like that, don't offend the users.

If all you want is to stretch the display, resize your window to cover the full screen and use glViewport and appropriate values for the projection matrix. I could give you more advice if you'd post your drawing functions source code.